# Postive definite matrices with a particular eigenvector/eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-definite

Given $\vec v\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}$, suppose I want to find a symmetric, positive definite $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n }$ satisfying the eigenvalue equation

$A\vec v=\lambda \vec v $

One matrix that works is $A$ with matrix elements $A_{ij}=\lambda \frac{v_iv_j}{\vec v^T\vec v}$. Two questions:

(a) Are there other options? It seems there should be but I can't figure out how to prove it.

(b) If yes, what constraints can I put on $A$ satisfying this equation?

Comment: You need $\lambda > 0$ unless $v = 0$ because a symmetric matrix is positive definite iff all its eigenvalues are positive.

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing this out. I was assuming that implicitly, but wasn't specified

Comment: Extend  $v$ to a new set $v, u_2, ...,u_n$  of pairwise orthogonal vectors  (e.g. using Gram-Schmidt). Then take $v, u_2, ...,u_n$ as column vectors of a matrix $H:=(v, u_2, ...,u_n)$ and a diagonal matrix $\Lambda$ having $\lambda$ as first value in the diagonal, and only positive elements in the rest. Then take $A:=H\Lambda H^t$

Comment: The matrix that you suggest is not invertible (for $n \geq 2$), so it fails to be positive definite.

Comment: If we define
$$
A_t = \lambda t I + (1 - t) A
$$
where $A$ is the matrix you describe, then $A_t$ will satisfy your condition for $t > 0$.